# DJANGO - how can I filter an object filtering by another object filtered

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make an advanced filter with django objects but I just have no clue of how to do it.
I'll try to explain myself:

I have 2 objects:

Consumptions:

```
class Consumption(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición del modelo de Consumos"""

    STATES = [
        ('not-prevalidated', 'No prevalidado'),
        ('prevalidated', 'Prevalidado'),
        ('pendant', 'Pendiente validación cliente'),
        ('accepted', 'Aceptado'),
    ]

    client = models.ForeignKey('authentication.Client', verbose_name=("Cliente"), null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    access_date = models.DateField("Fecha de acceso", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    status = models.CharField("Estado", max_length=20, choices=STATES, null=False, blank=False)
```

and Clients

```
class Client(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Model definition for Client."""

company_name = models.CharField("Nombre de la empresa", max_length=150, default="Nombre de empresa", null=False, blank=False)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
dateadded = models.DateTimeField("Fecha de inserción", default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

And now I want to count all **clients** that has some **consumption** in '**pendant**' state and in **certain date**.
As you can see consumptions has one client related.

I've checked the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/ but I just can't get what I want.

Could someone help me? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up fixing OP's problem was a `distinct()` call to avoid any duplicate rows from being selected. Fair reminder though that in most cases, a call for `distinct()` isn't required. It's just that when queries span over multiple tables there's a chance for a row to be selected twice.

[read comments]

```
client_count = Client.objects.filter(
consumption__status="pendant",
consumption__access_date="2020-11-03").distinct().count()
```

When you say "I want to count the clients that has consumptions in certain state" what exactly do you mean? Can you provide more detail as to what exactly you are expecting?

The other answer with the following code will indeed count the number of clients that have consumptions in a certain state.

```
client_count = Client.objects.filter(
    consumption__status="pendant",
    consumption__access_date="2020-11-03").count()
```

**But** it will not count each client twice if the client has multiple 'consumptions', is that what you wish? If that's the case then perhaps filtering the consumptions is a better idea?

```
count = Consumption.objects.filter(
    status="pendant",
    access_date="2020-11-03").count()
```

This will give you a count of the total consumptions in that state, and if you wish to access all the clients then simply access `consumption.client`.

Comment: Okey let me try to explain it better:

In one hand we have Clients. In the other hand we have consumptions, every consumption has a client related and an state. I want to count all the clients that have one or  more consumptions in the 'pendant' status

Comment: Okey the problem was that there was some clients repeated. ".distinct()" fixed my problem

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's very weird that "distinct()" had to be used for something like this, I personally had forgotten that it existed. If anyone else reading this has any idea why this happened, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

lookup through the *span relation* as,

```
client_count = Client.objects.filter(
    consumption__status="pendant",
    consumption__access_date="2020-11-03").count()
```

Comment: It only counts consumptions, I want to count the clients that has consumptions in certain state

Comment: Have you not seen the usage of `filter(...)` method?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way:

```
from django.db.models import Count

client_count = Consumption.objects.filter(status='pendant',access_date=some_date).aggregate(client_count = Count('client'))['client_count']
```

Comment: It only counts consumptions, I want to count the clients that has consumptions in certain state

Answer (score 1):

Could this do the job:

```
nb_clients = Client.objects.filter(consumption_set__status='pendant',consumption_set__access_date__range=(start_date, end_date)).count()
```

doc backward relationship : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

doc range : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#range

Comment: "Cannot resolve keyword 'consumption_set'" it takes consumption_set like a field from consumption. I'm in django 2.2, might my the problem?

Comment: I mistaken related_name and related_query_name, This should work fine with consumption__status like in Wasiq W Answer , keep the range lookup if it is what you need.